# 404 Folder not Found

Tags: asp.net

I am having a site with the like URL EX : http://music.xxxxxxxxxx.com

Here in this site i need to redirect user typing with his name to his bolg
--> http://music.xxxxxxxxxx.com/username

where 'username' is his blog name

In my local System its working fine since iam using the custom errormode On

its geting redirected in my Local System to FileNotFound.aspx.

But its not working in server a 404

ERROR : The requested document was not found on this server.

its not able redirect to FileNotFound.aspx page in which my logic is implemented.

Please can any one help me out..

Thanking You 
Sudarshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS might be configured to look for HTML files in the folder, which means it will not pass the 404 to ASP.NET. You should be able to change the default file that it tries to load to make sure that an aspx file is last.